# Java unparseable date

Tags: java, datetime

There is the following code:

```
Date st = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(date);
```

And I get the following exception "Unparseable date: "2000-01-01T01:00:00Z" (at offset 4)". How can I fix it?

Comment: By passing in a string that's in the form "HH:mm"?

Comment: See that [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).. The answer is there.

Comment: Whaat value has date variable?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "2000-01-01T01:00:00Z" )
```

## Wrong Parsing Pattern

You defined a formatting pattern that says you expect the input string to be hours and minutes. But your input string has much more, years, months, and so on.

## java.time

As of Java 8 and later, the old java.util.Date/.Calendar and java.text.SimpleDateFormat have been supplanted by the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). Avoid the old classes whenever possible as they have proven to be confusing, troublesome, and flawed.

Your input string is using one of the standard date-time formats defined by [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Fortunately, java.time uses that format by default.

```
String input = "2000-01-01T01:00:00Z" ;
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline basically in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). You may adjust the value to a particular time zone (a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)), producing a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZonedId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( instant , zoneId ) ;
```

If you call `toString` on a ZonedDateTime, you will get a string like:

> 1999-12-31T20:00:00-05:00[America/Montreal]

The ZonedDateTime class extends the ISO 8601 format by appending the name of the time zone in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date st = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(date.substring(11,16));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this format instead:

```
Date st = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").parse(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleDateFormat` is very unforgiving. It expects you to pass a String that exactly matches the format string you initialized it with. If you pass "HH:mm" as its format string, it will not be able to handle any other format - it cannot handle a date with a year in it, etc. It will handle "3:56" (in which case you'll get Jan 1, 1970 at 03:56AM in your `Date`).

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat dtf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
Date date = dtf.parse(date);
dtf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String dateStr = dtf.format(date);
Date finalDate = dtf.parse(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")
```

Answer (score -1):

The date in the exception is an xml schema dateTime. Note that simply creating

```
SimpleDateFormat dtf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

Will not work entirely as you might think because the Z indicates "UTC" timezone and the parser is by default initialized as local time.

Also note that the schema dateTime has a variable definition, it can (optionally) have millisecond precision (0 or more milliseconds) and the timezone (if something other than Z) is not compatible with the format of SimpleDateFormat.

In short: xml date times are tricky with the default libraries. I have written a custom solution for handling them in our environment but you could also look at the joda time library which I believe handles them well. Or you could wait for the next java version which will have a new date API.

Comment: **This Answer is incorrect.** Putting single-quote marks around that `Z` causes the letter to be ignored during parsing. But that `Z` is vital information! The `Z`, stands for "Zulu" and says the date-time value is in the [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time zone, an offset of `00:00` from UTC. The single-quotes mean you are losing information. Furthermore, if an incoming string has an offset number such as `+05:30` rather than a `Z`, the parsing will fail as the single-quotes mean you expect exactly a single letter of "Z" to appear in all inputs.

Comment: The answer is not incorrect, you just read it wrong. The Z is indeed vital information (as I stated, it indicates UTC timezone). The fact that it is ignored by the quotes should be self-evident for those who know the class which is why I said you have to be careful as it will use local time.