# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-08-19T00:00:00"

Tags: java

I'm trying to parse a date from a string in Java. My string is "2015-08-19T00:00:00", and this is my code to parse it:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(format.parse(dateString).getTime());
```

However, I'm getting this error message when I run the code:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-08-19T00:00:00"
```

This must be really simple -- I don't know where I'm going wrong though.

Comment: Drop the trailing `Z` from your format, or add a timezone to the string containing the data.

Comment: `'T'` as well. neither `'` nor `T` are value date string format characters.

Comment: @MarcB See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html "Text can be quoted using single quotes (') to avoid interpretation".

Comment: @AndyTurner It is possible to change my input format. I have a LocalDateTime object, and I am calling toString on the date format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ". Is it possible to change that in order to keep the parse code the same?

Comment: Have you tried `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`?

Comment: @DasunCathir If you have a `LocalDateTime`, why convert to String and then to `Timestamp`? Just use `Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime)` (assuming Java 8, not Joda).

Comment: For the input? you're probably right about that if i changed the code parsing the date, but i just tested for formatting the input like that and it didn't work out.

Comment: more context: this is a string being sent to my server from an android app

Comment: any idea why this wouldn't add a timezone to the string containing the input data: startDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")?

Comment: @DasunCathir because LocalDateTime doesn't have a time zone. That's what makes it Local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Wrong Parsing Pattern

Your parsing pattern includes a `Z` on the end. That symbol means you expect an offset-from-UTC. But your input strings lacks any offset or time zone information. So your data does not match what you told Java to expect.

Either:

- Drop the `Z` from your pattern, or
- Add offset info to your data (preferred).

If your data is meant to represent a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), then append literally a single character `Z` (short for "Zulu"). If meant for a moment in a specific offset such as India, append an offset such as `+05:30`.

Even better: Read on, use new classes.

## java.time

Java 8 brings the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), supplanting the old troublesome java.util.Date/.Calendar & java.text.SimpleDateFormat classes.

For more info and example code, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32089010/642706) to this similar Question, [Java unparseable date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21730638/642706).